# Should we move the FAQ into the FAQ tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, meta, tag-wiki

We have the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag that we use to gather the community FAQ. It's index is: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Does it make sense for this index to simply live in the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq/info) and retire the old index post?

Yes, No, Waffles?

Comment: Aren't waffles always the answer? I think it's a trick question. That aside, if it gets moved to the tag wiki (and now that tag wikis can be edited on the per-site meta), would it be synced with the per-site metas as well?

Comment: yeah the sync story is another advantage ... my plan though is only to sync stuff the community decided not to edit.

Comment: Cool, this sounds like a good idea to me then. There would be slightly more friction in updating the index, but that's pretty trivial.

Comment: As an aside: Interacting with the OP of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121705/where-can-i-ask-a-how-to-get-started-question-on-stackexchange-site-with-respe) has prompted me to go find the FAQ for tag wikis....and I can't find it. Is there one?

Comment: If there is, it's not linked for the [FAQ index](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) as far as I can see...

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to have an index anywhere you may as well slide it into the tag itself as it's supposed to be the jumping point for people fresh to the tag use.

To make it more visible, launch the info tab by default if the tag wiki is over a certain scads amount of characters. The longer, the more likely it is to be something of a read.

Comment: or if the tag has more than X questions. If it has more than X and no wiki, nag users with a dropdown to show the tag wiki some love.

Answer (score 0):

A few down-sides I can think of off hand...

1. **It'd no longer be available as a target for [dup-closing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/*%22%20-%5Bfaq%5D%20-%5Bfaq-proposed%5D%20closed:1).**

   This may not even be a down-side. If it is, we could probably just revive [a meta faq question for that purpose...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)
2. **Editing requirements would be considerably higher.**

   However, with suggested edits low-rep users could still suggest changes - which could then be approved along with the addition of the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag when necessary. This is a rather appealing workflow.
3. **[Justin Standard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140171/justin-standard) loses a bunch of meta rep dating back to August of '08.**

   He's a pretty cool dude, so I don't think he'd be all that upset, but... The *principle* of the thing!

Comment: shog, I allowed suggested edits on child meta tag wikis btw

Comment: Ah, cool - I'm a bit behind on recent changes :-)

Comment: @Shog9: `seen May 6 '11 at 13:45` - I don't think he'd mind. His activity says the last time he even did anything here *was* back in '08...